# How to use Group by clause in select statement

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-update, sql-order-by

```
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(50)
SET @Result = (select top 1
    ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,CheckIn,'2014-05-15 03:30:32.507') / 60.0 / 60.0),2)
  from CheckInCheckOut
  where UserId_Fk=3
  order by CheckInCheckOutId desc) 

update CheckInCheckOut 
set CheckOut='2014-05-15 03:30:32.507',CountHours=@Result 
where CheckInCheckOutId = (select top (1) CheckInCheckOutId  
           from CheckInCheckOut 
           where UserId_Fk = 3
           order by CheckInCheckOutId desc )
```

When I try to use this I get error as :

```
 'Column "CheckInCheckOut.CheckInCheckOutId" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

In this case , how to do group by clause in select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use appropriate aggregation function to define max CheckInCheckOutId:

```
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(50),@MaxCheckInCheckOutId int

--this value is calculated one time for the whole batch
set @MaxCheckInCheckOutId = (select MAX(CheckInCheckOutId) from CheckInCheckOut where UserId_Fk=3)

set @Result = (select ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,CheckIn,'2014-05-15 03:30:32.507') / 60.0 / 60.0),2)
  from CheckInCheckOut where UserId_Fk=3 and CheckInCheckOutId=@MaxCheckInCheckOutId) 

update CheckInCheckOut 
set CheckOut='2014-05-15 03:30:32.507',CountHours=@Result 
where CheckInCheckOutId = @MaxCheckInCheckOutId
```

Some tips:

1. You also didn't mention your edition of SQL Server, maybe it would be better to use CTE (common table expression) in higher than 2000 servers.
2. Here you can face with parameter sniffing, so "option (recompile)" or smth like that will be required for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using an aggregate function in your query, if you use another attribute which is not in any aggregate function, you need to mention it in the `group by` clause.
In the beginning of your t-sql:

```
SET @Result = (select top 1 ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,CheckIn,'2014-05-15 03:30:32.507') /    60.0 / 60.0),2)
      from CheckInCheckOut
      where UserId_Fk=3
      group by CheckInCheckOutId
      order by CheckInCheckOutId desc)
```